# Hangfire and WebHook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webhooks, hangfire

I have one WebAPi project and I am using Hangfire and Webhook in it. In Hangfire I have a recurring job in which I need to call my webhook notifyall controller.

I can easily post notify request if I have these two in two different projects. But How I should handle it in single project?

Posting to web API from withing the same web api is surely a bad design. I am looking for alternatives?

Comment: why not write a service that contains a method that executes the notify all code. Modify the controller to call the service.  Then instead of hangfire calling the controller have it also use the service.

Comment: Notify All method is an extension to APIController by webhook .net. I think it can only be called within the controller so that all the subscribers are notified by webhook.

Comment: Forgive me I haven't used the Webhook library so I probably shouldn't be commenting at all but I do have a question.  In their documentation it says "When an event happens in a service, a notification is sent in the form of an HTTP POST request to registered subscribers." Wouldn't that imply that your only solution is an HTTP Post.  I totally get what you're saying when you say you feel it's bad design, but I'm not sure you have an alternative.  There are worse design antipatterns :)